# Перекодировать htmlentities в человеческий текст

Tags: php, кодировка

Доброго времени суток. 
Средствами PHP получаю страницу с сайта, которую хочу парсить. 
В некоторых, критически важных полях нахожу вместо текста полный

```
&amp;#1087;&amp;#1088;&amp;#1080;&amp;#1086;&amp;#1073;&amp;#1088;&amp;
```

Декодер Лебедева успешно кодирует этот бред

> HTML-Entities → UTF-8

`html_entity_decode`, которую советуют на многих форумах делает из этого потока

```
&#1086;&#1089;&#1090;&#1072;&#1074;&#1082;&#1072;
```

То есть нельзя сказать, что не работает... но не так, как хотелось бы.
Подскажите, что делать?

Comment: @Afftobus, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Сначала, очевидно, нужно заменить все "`&amp;`" на "&". Можно обычным `str_replace`. После этого `html_entity_decode` работает нормально:

```
<?php
echo html_entity_decode(
   "&#1087;&#1088;&#1080;&#1086;&#1073;&#1088;", 
   ENT_COMPAT, 
   "UTF-8"
);
?>
```

Вывод:

```
приобр
```

Answer (score 0):

Костыль костыльный, но работает.

```
function Unicode2Charset($string, $charset = 'UTF-8') {
    $string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_NOQUOTES, $charset);
    return preg_replace(
        '~&#(?:x([\da-f]+)|(\d+));~ie',
        'iconv("UTF-16LE", $charset, pack("v", "$1" ? hexdec("$1") : "$2"))',
        $string
    );
}
$string = '&amp;#1087;&amp;#1088;&amp;#1080;&amp;#1086;&amp;#1073;&amp;#1088;&amp;';

echo Unicode2Charset($string); // OutPut приобр&
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо! 

Неужели нет стандартной функции?!

Comment: стандартная есть она ниже, просто эта кастомная с более тонкой настройкой.